# Test Driven Development: How do I test my forms in the play framework using scala?

Tags: scala, frameworks, tdd

I am working on a form for my web application, I would like to test the input fields in a form I have created to make sure they will produce the desired results. I am completely new to TDD, so I am not sure on how to make fake inputs to test my constraints I have on the input fields.

Could anybody offer any documentation on this or post some sample code?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what a basic test might look like:

```
import org.scalatest.FunSpec
import play.api.data.Form
import play.api.data.Forms._

class TddFormTest extends FunSpec {
  case class Data(name: String, age: Int)
  val form = Form(mapping("name" -> text(minLength = 1, maxLength = 25), "age" -> number)(Data.apply)(Data.unapply))
  describe("a basic form") {
    it("accepts name input") {
      form.bind(Map("name" -> "Exactly 25 characters...."))
    }

    it("requires name to be non-empty") {
      val boundForm = form.bind(Map("name" -> ""))
      assert(boundForm.hasErrors)
      assert(boundForm.errors("name").head.message == "error.minLength")
    }

    it("does not accept names over 25 characters") {
      val boundForm = form.bind(Map("name" -> "whoah this name is too long!!!!!!"))
      assert(boundForm.hasErrors)
      assert(boundForm.errors("name").head.message == "error.maxLength")
    }

    it("fills from Data") {
      val filledForm = form.fill(Data("Testerton Testertop", 42))
      assert(!filledForm.hasErrors)
    }

    it("binds to Data") {
      val name = "Testerton Testertop"
      val age = 42
      val boundForm = form.bind(Map("name" -> name, "age" -> age.toString))
      assert(Data(name, age) == boundForm.get)
    }
  }
}
```

It's testing the form directly using a simple Map to provide the values that would come from the form. You could bind to a Request object instead, but this is an easy way to test drive the form constraints directly. You could supplement this with a happy path test of the form integrated into a page to make sure everything is hooked together properly. That sort of thing has some coverage here: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaFunctionalTestingWithScalaTest